# How to get the url of the root page in template in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

[pageurl can do it with a Page object](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/topics/writing_templates.html#internal-links-tag), but I am not sure how to get the root page object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The URL of the root page is `/`. Just write `<a href="/">` - no need to use a template tag.

(You might think that's cheating, but it's literally the definition of the root page.)

If you have your `include(wagtail_urls)` line in urls.py rooted at a path other than `/`, and don't want to hard-code that path in your template, you can use: `{% url 'wagtail_serve' '' %}` (note the empty string after `'wagtail_serve'`).

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I meant the root page defined under Settings in Wagtail CMS. Not the root page of the whole site.

Comment: You mean the one you select under Settings -> Sites? Yes, that's the one I'm talking about too. When you select a page there, you are choosing which page you want to appear at the URL "/".

Comment: Or If I do it in Django way, ie. {% url 'name_of_wagtail_root_view' %}, I want to know what that name is. My url setting:

`re_path(r'^blog/', include(wagtail_urls)),`

I tried `{% url 'wagtail_serve' %}`, but it gives error:

`Reverse for 'wagtail_serve' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/((?:[\\w\\-]+/)*)$']`

Comment: The problem is "/" is not the root of my site. Please see the above comment. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I understand now - please see my updated answer.

Comment: `wagtail_urls` seems to be deprecated. See updated answer with new tags tag.

Answer (score 6):

If you use wagtail_modeltranslation and want to get the translated root page url (eg: example.com/fr/ for French), you can use `{% pageurl request.site.root_page %}`.

For wagtail versions > 2.9:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% wagtail_site as current_site %}
```

Then either use `{% pageurl current_site.root_page %}` or `{{ current_site.root_url }}`.

Answer (score 5):

To show the site root page in a wagtail template,  add the following to your page template:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
<a href="{{ request.site.root_url }}">Site Url</a>
```

This code is deprecated. Starting with wagtail 2.9, the preferred option is `{% wagtail_site %}`. View [wagtail 2.9 release notes](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/releases/2.9.html#removed-support-for-django-2-1)

Comment: This doesn't work: "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect."

Comment: @danny you should try `{{ page.get_site.root_url }}`

Comment: @jcuot thank you this worked!

Answer (score 3):

With wagtail version > 2.12.2 you need to import `{% wagtail_site as current_site %}`

and then you can use: `{{ current_site.root_url }}`in your template.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [wagtail-localize](https://www.wagtail-localize.org/) this will get you the homepage for your current locale

`{% pageurl page.get_site.root_page.localized %}`

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Wagtail, 5.1.1, you can use the `{% url 'wagtail_serve' '' %}` template tag.

For example, in html it would be written:

```
<a class="footer-links" href="{% url 'wagtail_serve' '' %}">Blog</a>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to load `wagtailcore_tags` before using the `{% url %}` tag, because `{% url %}` is a standard tag built into Django, not part of Wagtail. (You might have other things on the template that require `wagtailcore_tags`, though.)

Comment: You're correct. I've updated this. The accepted answer is correct, and mentions the need for the need for `include(wagtail_urls)`.